# How to generate a Docker image for multiple architures using dotnet 7?

Tags: .net, docker

Is there any way to generate the image for more than 1?

I've followed this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows), but it's only for a single architecture.

Comment: See if it is helpful [link](https://medium.com/@hafiz.ubikm/docker-image-for-multiple-architectures-using-net-7-2b8efdba7b85)

Comment: Should not docker itself abstract over the architecture?

Comment: @GuruStron It doesn't. The images still contain binaries for a set of architectures.

Comment: @SuperJMN Yep, you are right. Have you tried [buildx](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/)?